# problem mocking restTemplate with mockMvc

Tags: java, mockito

I need to write a unit test for a rest controller endpoint that calls a service which calls RestTemplate exchange()

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    Myservice myservice;

    @GetMapping("todo")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getTodo() {
        String todoJson = myservice.getTodo();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(todoJson);
    }
}
```

Here's my service class

```
@Service
public class Myservice {

    public String  getTodo() {
        ResponseEntity<Todo> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", HttpMethod.GET, null, Todo.class);
        Todo todo = response.getBody();
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(todo);
    }
}
```

And test case

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyControllerTestJunit5 {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    MyController myController;

    @Mock
    Myservice myservice;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void mockResttemplate() throws Exception {
        Todo todosample = new Todo(5,6,"myfield", true);

        ResponseEntity<Todo> responseEntity  = ResponseEntity.ok(todosample);

        when(restTemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.eq(Todo.class)))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/todo"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
        String myresult = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        System.out.println("response: " + myresult);
    }
```

printing the response at the end shows that the response is empty.  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you expect to get the JSON representation of `todosample` object. The problem in the test is that you are mocking `Myservice` by annotating it with `@Mock`. That mocked service is used by `MyController` because it's annotated with `@InjectMocks`. As a result, when you make a call to the `/todo` endpoint the controller calls `myservice.getTodo()` which returns `null` as the `Myservice` mock is not configured to return anything else. After that, the `null` value gets propagated to the `ResponseEntity` body which materializes to the empty OK response in your test.

I believe a better approach for this kind of test will be to just mock `Myservice` and configure it properly. The first part is done already as I mentioned. The configuration is easy. You should just replace `restTemplate.exchange` call configuration with the `myservice.getTodo()` one. Something like this should work:

```
@Test
public void mockResttemplate() throws Exception {
    String todosampleJson = "{}"; // just empty json

    when(myservice.getTodo()).thenReturn(todosampleJson);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/todo"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    String myresult = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    System.out.println("response: " + myresult); // will print "{}" now
}
```

And then you can have a separate test for `Myservice` where you have to mock `restTemplate.exchange` call.

Of course technically, you can still get away with mocking the `restTemplate` in your `MyController` test but then you have to make sure you instantiate the real `Myservice` instead of the mocked version of it. However, in this case you would expose the implementation details of `Myservice` to the `MyController` class, which kinda contradicts the MVC pattern.